# apache rewrite woes

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

Having some problems with apache rewrite.
The whole of my site operates over SSL (online store), apart from one page (visit_us.php) with a google maps API on it (since Google charges $$$$$ for HTTPS access). With this page displaying a message every time that it included unsecure content (which sounds bad to any end-user), i implemented a simple apache rewrite rule to switch to port 80 and it works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect all http traffic to https, unless visit_us.php is requested
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/visit_us\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect https traffic for visit_us.php to http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/visit_us\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, upon integrating the twitter widget (which can only operate over HTTP), i realised i would have to add the social networking page to the list that operates over port 80.
I thought this would be simple enough, adding the social.php page to the list above, as so:

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect all http traffic to https, unless visit_us.php or social.php is requested
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/visit_us\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect https traffic for visit_us.php and social.php to http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/visit_us\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/social\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In my site, i explicitly link to HTTP, rather than HTTPS. However, although it still works for the visit_us.php page, the social.php page seems to be ignored and requests constantly end up on port 443.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Apache questions are almost always off-topic for this stackoverflow.com. There is always serverfault or the webmasters stckexchange sites.

Comment: i'll bear that in mind for the future, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#redirect https traffic for visit_us.php and social.php to http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/visit_us\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/social\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You cannot use default `AND` logic for rewrite conditions here -- it has to be `OR` logic instead (*read your conditions in plain English and you will see the flaw*).

**Two approaches:**

**1.** Explicitly specify that `OR` logic should be used:

```
#redirect https traffic for visit_us.php and social.php to http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/visit_us\.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/social\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**2.** Merge two rewrite conditions into one (where OR logic is used):

```
#redirect https traffic for visit_us.php and social.php to http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(visit_us|social)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: aah, didn't think that AND was the default operator, since the visit_us still worked. but the latter seems much more appropriate and works great, thanks for the tip!